# Image in ScrollView with PageControl

Tags: uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

Hi I'm trying to develop an app with ScrollView and PageControl.

I would like i to recieve one picture for each page, how can I make it possible?

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven't found the answer yet, or anybody stumbles on this like I did,
there's a perfect example [here](http://code.davidjanes.com/blog/2009/09/26/uipagecontrol-uiscrollview/).

Comment: just was I was looking for. 1,5 years after you posted! Seems like you predict the future lol. but for real, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try out this framework : https://github.com/AdrianFlorian/AFImageViewer to present images in a scroll view using a page controll to indicate the current page.

I have't added documentation yet, but you can see examples if you clone the project.

You can easily: - download images from the internet in a separate thread by only giving an array of urls (image urls) - give it an array of UIImage objects - implement a delegate and manage the image for each page yourself